# Why must controller be localhost when running KRaft mode

Tags: apache-kafka, kraft

In KRaft mode, the Kafka broker does not start unless if the controller listens on `localhost`. For example, either of the following does not work on my laptop:

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://10.0.0.48:9092,CONTROLLER://10.0.0.48:9093
listeners=PLAINTEXT://192.168.56.1:9092,CONTROLLER://192.168.56.1:9093
listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092,CONTROLLER://192.168.56.1:9093
```

If I replace the controller IP address with `localhost` in either of the above, `kafka-server-start.sh` starts successfully.

I get the following logs continuously in the failure scenario:

```
[2022-10-27 15:06:19,885] WARN [BrokerToControllerChannelManager broker=1 name=heartbeat] Connection to node 1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9093) could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2022-10-27 15:06:19,885] INFO [BrokerToControllerChannelManager broker=1 name=heartbeat]: Recorded new controller, from now on will use broker localhost:9093 (id: 1 rack: null) (kafka.server.BrokerToControllerRequestThread)
[2022-10-27 15:06:19,935] INFO [BrokerToControllerChannelManager broker=1 name=heartbeat]: Recorded new controller, from now on will use broker localhost:9093 (id: 1 rack: null) (kafka.server.BrokerToControllerRequestThread)
[2022-10-27 15:06:19,936] INFO [BrokerToControllerChannelManager broker=1 name=heartbeat] Node 1 disconnected. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

Until I get the following error and `kafka-server-start.sh` exits:

```
[2022-10-27 15:06:22,804] ERROR Exiting Kafka due to fatal exception during startup. (kafka.Kafka$)
java.util.concurrent.CancellationException
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.cancel(CompletableFuture.java:2468)
    at kafka.server.BrokerLifecycleManager$ShutdownEvent.run(BrokerLifecycleManager.scala:485)
    at org.apache.kafka.queue.KafkaEventQueue$EventHandler.run(KafkaEventQueue.java:174)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

It seems like it expects the controller to be `localhost`. If this is the case, why?

Answer (score 1):

I had to change `controller.quorum.voters` to match what's in `listeners`:
`controller.quorum.voters=1@192.168.56.1:9093`